# Error command gnuradio-companion for windows

Tags: windows, installation, gnuradio

miniforge3 windows
(gnuradio) C:\Users\gwgwa>gnuradio-companion
'gnuradio-companion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little cryptic, but it seems you're trying to run GNU Radio on a Windows machine. In this case, it may be useful to refer to the [Windows Install](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/WindowsInstall) section of the GNU Radio documentation. The [Radioconda Installer](https://github.com/ryanvolz/radioconda) referenced there is probably your best option.